# Transformations solving recurrence with generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

[image]
Why is

- $\sum_{n ≥3} a_{n-1}  z^{n-1}$    equal to   $(A(z) − 1 − z)$?
- $\sum_{n ≥3}a_{n-2}  z^{n-2}$   equal to     $(A(z) − 1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geqslant3}a_{n-1}z^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geqslant2}a_nz^n = A(z) - a_0 - a_1z = A(z) - 1 -z. $$

$$\sum_{n\geqslant3}a_{n-2}z^{n-2} = \sum_{n\geqslant1}a_nz^n = A(z) - a_0 = A(z) - 1. $$

Comment: Why is a1 multiplied by z and a0 isn`t?

Comment: That follows from the definition $A(z)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_nz^n$.